# Metallic sound when brake the first time after a reverse

Tags: brakes, noise, mercedes-benz

A Klass Mercedes (180d Automatic 2017)

When i go in reverse and then i set the car to drive, the first time i will use the brake it will make a metallic sound a sound like a hammer hits something metallic.

It happend only if i set the car in reverse and go a bit in in and then i set it in drive and brake after some meters.

I have tried to bring the car to Mercedes they said that everything was okay.

Comment: Sounds like something in the drivetrain.  If this is a RWD vehicle I'd look at the driveshaft universal joints.  If this is FWD then look at the CV joints.

Comment: @jwh20 It's a FWD and i'm afraid that the issue is in CV joints as you said. Time a go i had to replace the right side U Joints due to an accident and the mechanic was not that good..

Comment: Often CV joints will make quite a bit of noise when you turn the steering wheel to its limit while driving (slowly).  But sometimes you just have to get in there and inspect them.

Comment: @jwh20 it happens that when i turn the steering wheel to it's limit and drive slowly that the car start to "jump" but it's not always happens

Comment: When you took it to the Mercedes service center did the service writer hear the problem you are discussing here?  If so, then it's quite possible that it's OK.  On the other hand if you don't trust them, take it to another dealer or an independent shop for a 2nd opinion.  I'm not sure how someone here is going to be able to diagnose better than someone who actually inspected the car.